# Can a weapon have a negative Strength requirement through upgrades?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

Through the use of Upgrade Scrolls, is it possible to reach a negative strength requirement? Assuming there are enough Upgrade Scrolls in the game and you don't die due to your lack of quality armour or weapon.

Comment: I will try to test this, but I doubt anyone will ever be able to. The game does not give enough Scrolls of Upgrade to make it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I once got a glaive on Lvl 1 of the dungeon and I was like "This is great!" I then proceeded to put every scroll I found into it. By the Tengu I got it to +20 and it did require a minumum strength of -2 to use. I was playing an Assassin and was eventually killed by ranged attacks (Dwarf Warlock).